# What's a regular expression to break a query string where variables may contain '&'?

Tags: javascript, regex, web

How can a JavaScript regular expression be written to separate a URI into query string variables, where the variables itself might contain the '&' character?

I'm currently using the following code- but if any of the variables contain an & embedded it won't capture the rest of that variable. How can this be alleviated?

```
function uriParameters() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}
```

Comment: To avoid going through all that hassle, **encode** your parameters first before sending them.

Comment: I've no control of what's passed in the URI. I'm just breaking it apart and reading it in JS.

Comment: Can `&` occur in both name and value?

Answer (score 2):

Simple question: what variables do you expect from this?

```
a=b&c&d=e
```

Is it ?

```
a=b&c, d=e     //or 
a=b  , c , d=e
```

So there is an ambiguity, and your problem can't be resolved, **if** you don't have the *set of names*.

**UPDATE:** If query string contains only `name=value` pairs,and there are no single `name` parameters, then you can extract those pairs by below script:

```
 function getUriParameters( uri ){
     //Some sequence of chars that can't be matched in query string
     var SYN = ",,,";
     var vars = {};
     uri.split("=")
        .map(function(value){    //Replacing last '&' by SYN value
            return value.replace(/&([^&]*)$/,SYN+'$1');
        })
        .join("=")               //Restoring uri
        .split(SYN)              //
        .forEach(function(v){    //Storing 'key=value' pairs
             vars[v.split('=')[0]] = v.split('=')[1];
             //       key                 value
        });
     return vars;
 }
 //Usage-> getUriParameters("a=b&c&d=e")
 //Sample
 console.log( JSON.stringify(getUriParameters("a=b&c&d=e")) );
 //output -> {"a":"b&c","d":"e"}
```

Comment: I think the ambiguity can be resolved IF `&` can only occur in values.

Comment: of course, three different forms requires at least two assertions :)

Comment: Required outcome is a=b&c, d=e.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a special character which purpose is to break the url into multiple variables. If it is a value, it is encoded.

Also, I'd look at this answer for a complete function to handle parameters: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)